# Using PHP Mysql how can I get which condition satisfied from multiple OR condition in a sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have below query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `tbl_user` 
        WHERE `Code1`='114' 
        OR `Code2`='114' 
        OR `Code3`='114' 
        OR `Code4`='114' 
        OR `Code5`='114'";
```

I can find the column which satisfy the condition `Code1` or `Code2` or `Code3` ... by `array_search` of the return result.

But can I get any other easy solution?

Comment: unsure about what youa re asking

Comment: Are there just the 5 code columns?

Comment: I would like to see some table schema / sample data.

Comment: This question is showing symptoms of poor database table design.  Is it too late to normalize?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the result you want using the [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT *,
       FIELD(114, code1, code2, code3, code4, code5) AS code
FROM tbl_user
WHERE FIELD(114, code1, code2, code3, code4, code5) > 0
```

Output (for my [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7439d3ef0a525754886ea6ac31e617c0)):

```
code1   code2   code3   code4   code5   code
45      32      114     5       12      3
114     34      98      93      12      1
57      114     48      23      72      2
12      75      8       3       114     5
49      4       198     114     52      4
```

Note that if you want a string column name instead of just a number, you can use

```
CONCAT('Code', FIELD(114, code1, code2, code3, code4, code5)) AS code
```

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah, I thought about adding the `CONCAT` but I figured this was purer. I've made a note...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN predicate, as below

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE 114 IN(Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5);
```

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question which is to find out which column had 114 in it.

Comment: @Muhammad Saqlin, but how can I get from this query that which column is matched the recordset?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlin, the answer is perfect. Only suggestion is that if you provide a Reference, it should be official documentation of technologies e.g. php.net, oracle.com.

Comment: @Pupil this does not answer the question. Read OPs comment to this answer.

Comment: **if** this was the answer, we could close the page with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463423/2943403  However I don't feel that this is a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT col FROM (
   SELECT "Code1" AS col, Code1 AS value FROM tbl_user
   UNION ALL SELECT "Code2", Code2 FROM tbl_user
   UNION ALL SELECT "Code3", Code3 FROM tbl_user
) allValues
WHERE value=114;
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2940786/2693543

Answer (score 0):

if you need to select column names then

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_user.COLUMNS WHERE 114 IN(Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5);
```

The best way is to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA metadata virtual database. Specifically the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table...

SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
It's VERY powerful, and can give you TONS of information without need to parse text (Such as column type, whether the column is nullable, max column size, character set, etc)...