# MySQL query to get column name where my search condition meets

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database. I am given a value that occurs as a cell value in that table but I want to find the column name where my search condition meets. What is the most efficient way to find the column to which that value belongs?

But my search query to find the column name WHERE **user4** exist and **module_name = 'accounts'**. I am trying below but not working -

```
SELECT col FROM (
   SELECT "view_only" AS col, view_only AS value FROM module_access
   UNION ALL SELECT "limited_access", limited_access FROM module_access
   UNION ALL SELECT "full_access", full_access FROM module_access
) allValues
WHERE (value LIKE '%user4,%') AND (module_name = 'accounts');
```

My Sample Table Structure like below-

Table Name: module_access

```
module_name  |  view_only     |  limited_access  |  full_access
============================================================================
accounts     |  user1,user2,  | user3,user4,     | superadmin,admin,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sales        |  user1,user4,  | user3,           | superadmin,admin,user2, 
============================================================================
```

I refer this [Find column that contains a given value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940759/find-column-that-contains-a-given-value-in-mysql) and use below query and works but it is not the complete solution I want.

```
SELECT col FROM (
   SELECT "view_only" AS col, view_only AS value FROM module_access
   UNION ALL SELECT "limited_access", limited_access FROM module_access
   UNION ALL SELECT "full_access", full_access FROM module_access
) allValues
WHERE value LIKE '%user4,%';
```

Comment: If you used a properly designed relational database using standard principals you would not be in this pickle

Comment: "I am trying below **but not working**".  Maybe you should try to solve this problem?  Why did you no specify the complete error message that you did get?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. You are right. I am not expert on it. I am a beginner. Can you please edit my sample query to accomplish my task?

Comment: This seems like an attempt to make an existing problem worse, rather than correct it.  The database design *really should* be changed here.  But if for whatever reason you won't do that, what is the specific use case for this?  Perhaps this result should be derived in application logic instead of in the query itself?  But, again, querying data becomes *orders of magnitude easier* when the database is designed properly.

Comment: To give you an idea on a better design... "users" are a table, "modules" are a table, and "access levels" (or "roles") are a table.  Then you might have a table like "UserModuleAccessLevel" which is a linking table between the three, and would include foreign keys to the other three tables.

Comment: @David Yes. I can understand it and thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent was that you first query would return "limited_access", but instead it returned an error ("Unknown column 'module_name' in 'where clause'")

Fixing this problem:

```sql
SELECT col FROM (
   SELECT module_name, "view_only" AS col, view_only AS value FROM module_access
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT module_name, "limited_access", limited_access FROM module_access
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT module_name, "full_access", full_access FROM module_access
) allValues
WHERE (value LIKE '%user4,%') AND (module_name = 'accounts');
```

now this query returns: `limited_access`

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/4Iicve59)

But, as others noted, your database design is not correct.

Comment: Thank you so much @Luuk . It's the perfect answer I want for.